# How to change the font of label on the colorbar when plotting in xarray?

Tags: plot, python-xarray, colorbar

I am plotting a xarray dataset and I want to change the size of the label of the colorbar. This is the code I am using --

```
from cdasws import CdasWs
from cdasws.datarepresentation import DataRepresentation
cdas = CdasWs()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# getting data set

wind_dataset = cdas.get_datasets(observatoryGroup='Wind')

# obtaining variable
variables_wind = cdas.get_variables('WI_H1_WAV')

# obtaining data
wind_data = cdas.get_data('WI_H1_WAV', ['E_VOLTAGE_RAD1','E_VOLTAGE_RAD2'],
                     '2020-07-11T02:15:00Z', '2020-07-11T02:50:00Z',
                     dataRepresentation = DataRepresentation.XARRAY)[1]

# plotting 

wind_data['E_VOLTAGE_RAD2'].transpose().plot(cbar_kwargs={'label': "This is the new label"})
plt.yscale('log')
```

The plot looks like --
[image]

How can I change the fontsize of the label of the colorbar?